# Piping a program that uses WriteConsole

Tags: c++, stdout, pipe

I wanted to call _popen to get the results from an executable but it was blanking out.

I looked in debugger and found out the program uses Kernel32.WriteConsoleW to write a unicode string to the console, instead of using stdout.

How do I capture it?

Comment: Anyone know if I can redirect the handle of the child process and call ReadConsole on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to redirect the Output of a child process.

Have a look at [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Furthermore the application might use STD_ERROR_HANDLE instead of STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE.

Comment: Working on the most hacked up, messiest solution ever based on this link. Thanks. Basically I'm doing system("cls") then using CreateProcess giving the child process the parent's stdout, then using ReadConsoleOutputW and rebuilding the result out of that.

Answer (score 5):

Any output generated with `WriteConsole` will not be written to the redirection pipe. If a handle to a pipe or a file or anything else than a console is given to `WriteConsole`, it will fail with `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE` (6).

From [High-Level Console Input and Output Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683457(v=vs.85).aspx) on MSDN:

> ReadConsole and WriteConsole can only be used with console handles; ReadFile and WriteFile can be used with other handles (such as files or pipes). ReadConsole and WriteConsole fail if used with a standard handle that has been redirected and is no longer a console handle.

Answer (score 2):

The overkill solution: intercept calls to WriteConsoleW by hooking into the application on start. Probably not what you're looking for, and I'm sure there's an easier way. But it'll work for sure :)